# array with multiple options and response

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to create a menu where you could select multiple options and at the end/or in a box underneath we want it to display the value of the total amount of kcal selected in the products as well as a text box, we are not sure how to add a textbox underneath together with the answer, how do we fix this?

This is our current code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>

    </title>
    <style>
      #overskrift {
        background-color:#ccc;
        color:white;
        padding:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;

      }

      #verdier 
      {
        width: 300px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color:#FFFFCC;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        color:black;
        padding:20px;
        margin:20px;
      }

      #radioknapper{
        margin-left:150px;
        background-color:#ccc;
      }

      div{
        padding:5px;
      }

      #forbruk{
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      table, th, td, input{
        border:1px solid black;
        margin-left:4px;
        padding:5px;

      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="overskrift">
      Beregning av energiforbruket i ulike typer mat
    </div>

    <div id="ramme">
      <div id="tabellramme">
        <table id="tabellen">


          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>

      // datastruktur array med de ulike verdiene.

      var i=0;
      var j=0;
      var matvareListe = [];
      matvareListe[0]=["Lettmelk", 82, 6.6, 3, 9.6];
      matvareListe[1]=["Egg", 80, 6.9, 5.5, 0.7];
      matvareListe[2]=["Grovbrød", 103, 3.5, 1, 19.6];
      matvareListe[3]=["Smør", 36, 0.025, 4.1, 0.025];
      matvareListe[4]=["Gulost", 53, 4, 4.2, 0];

      var kaloriListe = [];

      var farger = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "lightgreen", "green", "lightblue"];

      // setter opp tabellen med de ulike matvarene:

      function settMatvareTabell(){
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
          var trTag = document.createElement("TR");
          var atrId = "atr"+i;
          var atId = "at" + i;
          trTag.setAttribute("id", atrId);
          document.getElementById("tabellen").appendChild(trTag);
          for(j=0; j<5;j++){
            var tdTag = document.createElement("TD");
            var t = document.createTextNode(matvareListe[i][j])
            tdTag.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById(atrId).appendChild(tdTag); 
          } 
          //console.log(atrId);
          var radioInput = document.createElement('input');
          radioInput.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
          radioInput.setAttribute('id', atId);

          radioInput.setAttribute('onclick', 'settEnergforbruk()');
          document.getElementById(atrId).appendChild(radioInput);
          //console.log(atId);


        }
      }

      function settEnergforbruk(){
        var sumCal = beregnKiloCalorier();

        alert(sumCal);
        // tegner kakediagram
        var normVerdier = normaliser(kaloriListe);

        tegnKake(cnv.getContext("2d"), normVerdier);   


      }

      function beregnKiloCalorier(){
        var i = 0;
        var sumKiloCal = 0;
        kaloriListe = []; // Tømmer linten
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){ // Går gjennom liten og legger til hvis radioknappen er på
          var atId = "at" + i;
          if(document.getElementById(atId).checked == true){  // skal taes med
            sumKiloCal = sumKiloCal + matvareListe[i][1];
            kaloriListe.push(matvareListe[i][1]);
          }

        }
        return(kaloriListe);
      }
      // ---------kakediagram verdier --------------



      // ------------------------------------------------
      function normaliser(arr) {

        var sum = arraySum(arr);
        var antall = arr.length;
        var utArray = [];

        for (var teller = 0; teller < antall; teller++) {
          utArray[teller] = arr[teller]/sum;
        }

        return utArray;       
      }

      // ------------------------------------------------
      function arraySum(arr) {

        var antall = arr.length;
        var sum = 0;

        for (var teller = 0; teller < antall; teller++) {
          sum += arr[teller];
        }

        return sum;        
      }

      // ------------------------------------------------
      function tegnKake(c, arr) {

        c.lineWidth = 2;

        c.strokeStyle = "black";

        var vinkel = 0;

        for(var teller = 0; teller < arr.length; teller++) {

          var vinkelstep = arr[teller]*Math.PI*2;

          c.fillStyle = farger[teller % (farger.length)];
          c.beginPath();
          c.moveTo(200, 200);
          c.arc(200, 200, 180, vinkel, vinkel + vinkelstep);
          c.closePath();
          c.fill();
          c.stroke();

          vinkel += vinkelstep;

        }

      }





      settMatvareTabell();

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your tag says jquery but you're not using it in your code.. did you mean to use that tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the Problem you are running into it that the function beregnKiloCalorier returns an array containing all the calorie values selected and you only need the sum.

To fix this change your settEnergforbruk function to something like this:

```
        function settEnergforbruk(){
            var calList = beregnKiloCalorier();
            console.log(calList);

            var calSum = 0;
            calList.forEach(function(element){
                calSum += element;
            });

            //result is the id if a <input type="text"> where you want the result to be shown
            document.getElementById("result").value = calSum + " KiloCalorier";

            // tegner kakediagram
            var normVerdier = normaliser(kaloriListe);

            tegnKake(cnv.getContext("2d"), normVerdier);   
        }
```

Also you should clean up the beregnKiloCalorier function a little to look like this:

```
        function beregnKiloCalorier(){
            var i = 0;
            kaloriListe = [];   // Tømmer linten
            for(i=0; i<5; i++){ // Går gjennom liten og legger til hvis radioknappen er på
                if(document.getElementById("at" + i).checked == true){      // skal taes med
                    kaloriListe.push(matvareListe[i][1]);
                }

            }
            return(kaloriListe);
        }
```

And as a final touch you should clean up your html code so that the script tag is in the head and not in the body. This will mess up the functionality however, but to fix that add `onload="settMatvareTabell();` to the start tag of your body.

The body should look something like this when done:

```
<body onload="settMatvareTabell();">

    <div id="overskrift">
        Beregning av energiforbruket i ulike typer mat
    </div>

    <div id="ramme">
        <div id="tabellramme">
            <table id="tabellen"></table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The result will be displayed here -->
    <input type="text" id="result"></input>
</body>
```

**Update:**

As requested here you have an example on how to display your data in a pie chart: [Example](http://pastebin.com/zMNaMPf9)

Its a bit hacked together but it should give you an idea on how to do this :)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to display the result % in a pie chart? as en example, 300 kcal would take up 80% while fat/proteins would take the remaining 20%

Comment: That depends on the data that you pi chart needs to show the data. If it auto scales depending on the sum of the values you put in you just have to calculate the sum for every value separately an then ad it to the pie chart. To display the name of what ever n% you are showing you would have to redo your beregnKiloCalorier function to return a 2d array with the first field being the name and the second one is the sum of all selected values

Comment: I see, what I had in mind was a pi chart scaling and adjusting depending on whats selected and displaying the different values. The total amount of Kcal would be one tab, Proteins in a different one, Fat in one and Carbs in one. Can you help me with this? pretty please?

Comment: For a pie chart you should have a look at an off the shelf solution like http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-pie-chart/ To switch tabs you can use divs that change to display:none when not selected (in case you can not find an off the shelf solution that supports this already). And to show the values you would add like a "key value pair" made up from food name and value to the chart. with value depending on the selected tab eg. Kcal or Proteins.

Comment: I one that suits it perfectly: http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/pie/new-year-resolution/ How can I impliment it into my code to work? Sorry if this is too much to ask for

Comment: I will have a look. Give me a few minutes :) I will change my answer accordingly when I'm done.

Comment: Ok done. The code requires the `canvasjs.min.js` to be in the same directory but this can easily be changed. Hope this helped you :)

Comment: Ok thank you very much, but sadly I dont know how to get it to work, would you pretty please help me a step further and get it running :3 I know  I already asked too much from you.

Comment: Did you download the canvasjs library ? If not go to http://canvasjs.com/download-html5-charting-graphing-library/ and click on the blue button. For the window that appears just enter a fake email ;) Next extract the zip file in the same folder as you code is in. Make sure that the canvasjs.min.js is in the same directory as you html page. And done :D

Comment: Ok thanks, that works, but how do I adjust it so that in the chart, it shows divided into kcal, fat, proteins, and carbs (thats what the different part of the table is). What I'm trying to say is that I want each section to represent each form of carb/protein rather than the food type. either way, thanks, this works like a charm currently :D

Comment: To do i would recommend changing your input data format to something easier to use like an array of json objects with a property for each thing. Then you can write a function that will run a foreach on your array and access the properties trough their name and add them all one by one to separate diagrams or multiple data elements inside the pi chart object thingy. If you have more questions let me know and we can move this into a chat or something similar :)

Comment: I do not have enough rep to use the chat function, sadly. Do you have any other suggestions for a way to chat.

Comment: You could send me your email address to b1720821@trbvn.com (10 minute mail) and i will respond to you. I don't want to show my email publicly in the internet and you probably don't want to either.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want people to completely understand what you are coding about, use English. It is very difficult to understand what your code does if you're commenting in your own language.

Anyways.
So if I understand you correctly you want to add up some kcal values and display it underneath your table? For that to happen you'll need some checkboxes/radiobuttons or input fields where the user needs to fill in a value or number. This way you can assign the total of the calculated values to an input field.

In your HTML
Checkbox: `<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>`
To extract the value of a checbox:
 
Javascript: `var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.checkbox:checked').value;`

In your HTML 
Radiobutton: 
`<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="1" checked/>`
`<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="0" />`

Javascript:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('radiobutton');
var radioValue;

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        // do whatever you want with the checked radio
        alert(radios[i].value);
        radioValue = radios[i].value;
        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}

var totalValues = checkedValue + radioValue;
```

To add a textbox hardocoded in your html:

In your HTML underneath the table:
`<input id="totalCkal" class="inputTotalCkal" type="text" name="totalCkal"/>`
Javascript:
`document.getElementById('totalCkal').value = totalValues;`

Comment: Sorry, but this doesnt seem to fix it, I want to have it like its working now, but instead of "alerting" whats selected, I want it to post it below with the total amount of kcals selected. Even when multiple "products" are selected.